# Search pattern in string using wildcard in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, pattern-matching, delphi-xe

I used to use HYPERSTR library for string processing routine. Now I use newer Delphi. I need to search a pattern in a string, for example the old function is `function IsMatchEx(const Source, Search:AnsiString; var Start:integer) : Integer;`. Actually I don't need the result value, I just wanna know if the pattern match with the string or not.

My old code (returns TRUE):

```
var
  StartPos: integer;
  FoundPos: integer;
begin
  StartPos := 1;
  FoundPos := IsMatchEx('abcdef', 'abcd?f', StartPos);
  if FoundPos > 0 then
    showmessage('match');
end;
```

I see that Delphi XE has TRegEx but I stil don't understand to use it.

These code doesn't return TRUE :

```
  if TRegEx.IsMatch('abcdef', 'abcd?f') then
    showmessage('match');
```

I also got same result when using `MatchesMask`.

Thanks.

Comment: Think you use '.' to match a single character.

Comment: Really? MatchesMask *should* have worked. Are you sure your test was valid?

Comment: @Rob, I mean MatchesMask doesn't work in my real case. By using the dot, my problem has solved. Sorry for late reply because I have to fix some codes so I can try the answer from MGH.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if ? represent a single character:

```
  if TRegEx.IsMatch('abcdef', 'abcd.f') then
    showmessage('match');
```

if ? represent any sting:

```
  if TRegEx.IsMatch('abcdef', 'abcd.*f') then
    showmessage('match');
```

Don't have XE so haven't tested.

Comment: Beware of the dot... ;) http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html, for example it would match abcdef, but it would also match abcd,f abcd/f, abcd(f, etc. Regex can use a more powerful syntax to get exactly what you need to match.

Comment: @user '.' don't match if you have newline characters i think, then you need to use '[.\n\r]' in place of '.'

Comment: Hmm.. I think there will be no new line. The input is hex string from a file. Somehow I think my `strtohex` has invalid result, so I have to fix it first and it's time to go back home! :)

Comment: With hex input you most likely want to use ldsandon's suggestion, to match what you actually want. [0-9a-fA-F]* should match hex.

Comment: Shouldn't the mask of the first example be 'abcd.?' rather than 'abcd.f' ?

Comment: @dummzeuch 'abcd.?' would accept the sting 'abcd' and then optionally one more character. So no, that should not be the mask as far as I understand the original question. You could use 'abcd.?f' if the question mark in the the question represents an optional single character.

Comment: @MGH sorry, must have been a bad day. What I wrote was garbage.

Answer (score 10):

Regular expression syntax is different. ? and * have different meanings. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html for an excellent introduction to regular expressions.
You would use something alike abcd[a-z]f or abcd\wf, or even other syntax, depending on what you would like to match.

Comment: +1 for link you provided alone. I'd also suggest that if you're going to spend any time with regexes, you invest in a copy of [RegExBuddy](http://regexbuddy.com). It's an invaluable tool for creating and testing regular expressions. (Not affiliated in any way - just a very happy customer for years now.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use TMask for wildchar matching:

```
TMask *m = new TMask("String to check");
bool isMatch = m->Matches("string to*");
delete m;
```

isMatch = true
(C++Builder code is simply translable in Pascal)