# Delphi: Advanced string search commands

Tags: delphi

`Kenneth` is a string. Let's say it contains `'justabcsome123texthaha'`.

***I know this already:***

To find text:

```
if(pos('bcsome12',Kenneth) > 0) then
```

To check length:

```
if(Length('Kenneth') > 10) then
```

> Question 1:

I want to find `'texthaha'`, but only if it is at the end of the string.

```
if(pos('texthaha',Kenneth) > 0) then
```

Sadly this will find it anywhere, even if it is in the middle. Is there a simple way?

> Question 2:

Is there a simple way to do a search, but with a `*` (any character in between)?

For example, if I want to search for `bcsome1*3text` and I don't care what character the `*` is. I think it's called a wildcard, isn't it?

```
if(pos('bcsome1'*'3text',Kenneth) > 0) then
```

I know the above doesn't work. but is there a similar way?
**Edit: Might be of importance: **Delphi version used is very old, not sure of the version, but it's from year 2006.**

Comment: Regex (TRegex in modern Delphis) can certainly achieve your goals, but might be a little overkill for your cases.

Comment: At least for the first part of your question you might look at [System.StrUtils](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.StrUtils).

Comment: Surely you can do the maths if you know the position of the start of the match, and the length of the two strings?

Comment: Try selecting help -> about from the menu.

Comment: it's a seperate program written in delphi that's why i can't use the about to check the version sorry. but as i said from 2006 so it's old and does not have all the things

Comment: Have you tried thinking about the maths involved here?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you mean for the `if Pos(Sub, S) = Length(S) - Length(Sub) + 1` right? I was actually thinking about it because I don't understant why the +1 at the end needs to be added because i thought it would be equal without the +1

Comment: Nevermind figured it out. don't count the characters before, instead look where search text begins so it needs +1. Thank you all

Comment: Good, I'm glad you were able to work this out for yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are functions [`EndsStr()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.StrUtils.EndsStr) and `EndsText()` (the latter is case-insensitive) in the `StrUtils` unit

But, you easily could provide the needed functionality with known functions (Pos also has an overloaded version with the third parameter in fresh Delphi):

```
NPos =  Length(S) - Length(Sub) + 1;
if PosEx(Sub, S, NPos) = NPos then...
```

or variant proposed by @Sertac Akyuz:

```
if Copy(S, NPos, Length(Sub)) = Sub ...
```

The second problem might be solved with function like [`MatchesMask()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Masks.MatchesMask)

```
 if MatchesMask(Kenneth, '*bcsome1*3text*')...
```

Comment: A similar approach would be to make use of TStringHelper declared iin SysUtils and write _Kenneth.EndsWith('texthaha')_

Comment: For known functions, Copy would be a better test since any pattern can be found multiple times in a string.

Comment: Awesome for the first question `if Pos(Sub, S) = Length(S) - Length(Sub) + 1 then`... works nicely to find if it's at the end of the string (although i still try to understand the logic behind it lol). For the second question, the MatchesMask command can't be used I guess because the Delphi version used is probably too old, it's from 2006 so i have to find a workaround if possible for the MatchesMask

Comment: MatchesMask is rather old function. Have you included `Masks` in your `uses`?

Comment: Also consider note of @Sertac Akyuz about possible multiple occurences of substring - so I changed code to `PosEx`

Comment: When I put Masks; in uses i get "Error: Declaration expected but identifier 'Masks' found".
With PosEx i get "Error: Undeclared identifier: 'PosEx'". Probably because of the old version used. Pos works though, so that's nice

Comment: Your unit contains (usually long) `uses` clause at the top. Add Masks there.

Comment: @Linda Everything that has been suggested to you for use (masks and strutils units) existed already 2002, maybe even earlier. If you don't have those, it can only mean that you have an illegal warez version.

Comment: thanks MBo and tom. That's good to know. i tried adding Masks to the uses, and it gives me Fatal: File not found: 'Masks.dcu', probably because it's not included, Makes sense now. @tom it's just based on delphi.

Answer (score -2):

To get the last occurrence, try `LastDelimiter` (see [help](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SysUtils.LastDelimiter)). For wildcards, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989478/search-pattern-in-string-using-wildcard-in-delphi).

Comment: Regarding the wildcards answer:
I tried the TRegEx command with

`if TRegEx.IsMatch('abcdef', 'abcd.f') then` ...

It gives me this error: **Error: Undeclared identifier: 'TRegEx'**

So the delphi version used is probably too old and doesn't have it.**Is there an alternative?**

Comment: It is always a good idea to specify the Delphi version in the question or the tags.

Comment: i don't know the exact version, but it's **very old delphi version used from 2006**. So i need to find easy alternative ways. So for the first question I thought about "looking to the right of the found text" and if there is nothing, because its the end (of the string Kenneth), then you know the 'texthaha' searched for is at the end of the string.

Comment: LastDelimiter tests for each character in the delimiters you provide, not what is being asked. From the link you posted: *"`Delimiters` is a string where each character is a valid delimiter."*.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz thanks for the correction, you are right.